# Autenticação Angular 2 - Servlet Java

Tags: java-ee, angular, servlet

Estou com um problema ao utilizar uma API à qual não posso realizar alterações, acontece da seguinte forma, tenho um servlet que extende de uma biblioteca de segurança, essa biblioteca se encarrega de fazer os logins, permitir a utilização dos métodos no servlet, etc.

Quando vou pelo navegador, primeiro faço o request do servlet para o login, e logo após isso faço o request de um outro método do meu servlet, que retorna informações de um banco qualquer. Tudo retorna corretamente, porém fazendo isso do Angular 2 a coisa muda, faço o login, normalmente, e quando faço o request dos dados ele me retorna uma mensagem, como se eu não tivesse feito o login.

Me parece que o problema é que o http.get() do angular 2, realiza as requisições e logo em seguida morre completamente, ainda que o HttpService seja um serviço injetável.

Há alguma forma de criar um container único sem perder a sessão do login que fiz anteriormente?

Comment: Você chegou a verificar se pelo navegador algum cookie é salvo ? OBS: Tente reproduzir o login com alguma ferramenta de requisições como o Postman.

Comment: Realmente, não vi antes mas agora ao logar via navegador foi salvo um 'JSESSIONID'. Estou baixando o Postman agora para verificar isso. Mas vou tentar injetar esse cookie na próxima requisição.